# Open default Reminder app programatically

Tags: ios, swift, openurl

I'm trying to open iOS reminder app on button click.

```
@IBAction private func btnReminderTapped(_ sender: UIButton){
    
    if let url = URL(string: "x-apple-reminder://"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) { (isDone) in
            
        }
    }
}
```

Which I click on button in console I see the following log:

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "x-apple-reminder://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

How can I open the reminder app programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change url to `x-apple-reminderkit://`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26728896)

Comment: @Panda How does it not provide an answer to the question?

Comment: It appears to answer the question, but it could benefit from a little bit of explanation of why the `kit` needs to be added to the end.

Comment: Thanks man. Its working!! I think Apple has added `kit` suffix in url schemes.